# compile typescript for node js in visual studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have created nodejs typescript application. The main file as standart is `app.ts`. If I will put all code in `app.ts` application will work correctly. But if I have a typescript file added by references like:

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Server/serverController.ts" />

var _ = require('underscore');

import server = ServerCtrl;

var controller: server.ServerCtrl = new server.ServerCtrl();
controller.startServer();
```

application throws error becouse it cant find ServerCtrl. As I see the compilled js file is:

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Server/serverController.ts" />
var _ = require('underscore');
var server = ServerCtrl;
var controller = new server.ServerCtrl();
controller.startServer();
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

So then I push F5 (Start) button to debug application throws error.
The question is how to create typescript application for nodejs using references and compile/debug it correctly in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these two lines...

```
/// <reference path="Server/serverController.ts" />
import server = ServerCtrl;
```

For your own code, use a proper import...

```
import server = require("./Server/serverController");
```

Comment: Visual Studio says "Cannot find external module file by specified path". So then I run application nodejs says "Cannot find module 'Server/serverController.ts'"

Comment: Remove the .ts extension and double check the path is right.

Comment: The result is the same.Node js says "Cannot find module 'Server/serverController'". But if i push Ctrl+Left_Mouse Visual Studio correctly goes to serverController.ts file. But again highlight "Server/serverController" with an error "Cannot find external module file by specified path"

Comment: Can you try starting the path with dot-slash, i.e. "./Server/ServerController"

Comment: I have try in another IDE (webstorm) with test project, the problem is the same. If I put `./` before file name typescript says: error TS2306: File 'E:/Project/test/testModule.ts' is not an external module.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
I just remove `module` statement from included file. Something like:

```
//before
module ServerController {
    export class ServerCtrl{ /* code */ }
}

//after
export class ServerCtrl{ /* code */ }
```

then using code from Steve Fenton post like:

```
import serv = require('./Server/ServerController');
```

all works!